# how to disable full page cache in magento 2 for any particular controller

Tags: caching, magento2

i am developing one front end module in magento.I need to disable or escape the full page cache for my particular controller.How to achieve it programetically in magento 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make block for your page and then you need to make cache disable for that.

Blocks can be set as **non-cacheable** by setting the **cacheable** attribute `false` in layout XML files. For example

```
<block class="Block\Class" name="blockname" cacheable="false" />
```

Pages containing such blocks are not cached.

Comment: Thank you sunny .It's working.really you made my effort very simpler.

Comment: This disable cache of whole page not only of block.